# Is it a good idea to create commands as Spring bean in the CQRS design pattern in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, design-patterns

I've always used CQRS design pattern in Spring where Commands are simple POJOs and not Spring Beans (annotated with `@Component`). However, I recently started to wonder what would happen if those commands are treated as beans. I do not have a good feeling creating commands as beans but it's always a good idea ot have a second opinion on it for educative purposes.

Kind regards.

Comment: _Commands_ are data objects, and beans should be service objects. Command _handlers_ may be beans.

Comment: Implementation of CQRS pattern in spring boot can easly be done with https://albanoi.defrimhsn.com/ which is a OSS. You need just to define commands and handlers, the mapping between a handler and command is taken care by the built in gateway.